# Angular material not working in angular version 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular9

I'm updated the angular version 8 to angular 9 and also updated angular material to version 9 but it's not working and not showing any error. how to fix it.

here is code
material module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

 @NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule
  ] 
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

app-component.html

```
<h3>Stroked Buttons</h3>
 <div class="example-button-row">
  <button mat-stroked-button>Basic</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Primary</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button color="accent">Accent</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button color="warn">Warn</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button disabled>Disabled</button>
  <a mat-stroked-button routerLink=".">Link</a>
 </div>
```

app.module

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform browser/animations';
 import { MaterialModule } from './angular-material/material/material.module';
  import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';



@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: 1. Did you update to angular-material 9.0.0? 2. what does "not working" mean?

Comment: yes, I update angular-material 9.0.0. . and I import mat button module but it showing simple button

Comment: Show the code you're using for the mat-button, then. Basically we need enough info in the _question itself_ to help you figure out what's going wrong. Focusing on the button not styling/appearing as expected is a specific enough problem.

Comment: add `MatButtonModule` in `imports` array of AppModule

Comment: @ShubhamPatil This is the simplest recreation of the setup based on what you've said: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gputfr. Can you provide either error messages or details of what's not working. Edit: Prashant has the answer

Comment: there is no error message.

Comment: What happens if you also export all the material modules in your `material.module.ts` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to also add any material modules to the exports like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 

import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [ MatButtonModule ],
   exports: [ MatButtonModule ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

This is an example from a material.module I am using in a project:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

const mat = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...mat,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...mat,
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

This way everything that is added to the array will be imported and exported to other modules.

Comment: is it required to create `MaterialModule` ts file

Comment: No not required. You could import all of the modules in the app.module.ts or any other module declared. This is just for maintainability.

Comment: There is some issues with Angular 9 and Angular Material, I did add in export and import but I get error: This likely means that the library (@angular/material/sidenav) which declares MatSidenav has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Comment: @MJX Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are still struggling, and I don't know why this issue has been down voted, I just restarted my visual studio code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Also, remember to add this in your global (styles.css) styled `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

This was the issue for me after a series of upgrades, coming from version 9 up to 12.

Answer (score 1):

The angular material library (@angular/material/*) has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy(vs.9).

Add in package.json

```html
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
```